# Reading characters from a text file

Tags: file-io, postscript

I have an assignment to read characters one by one from one text file and write them to another text file using post script. I am to the point where I can read line by line from a text file and write the line to another.

This version works...

%!PS

```
/infile (input.txt) (r) file def % open files and save file objects
/outfile (output.txt) (w) file def
/buff 128 string def % your buffer for reading operations
{ % loop
        infile buff readstring
        { %ifelse
                outfile exch writestring
        }
        { %else
                outfile exch writestring
                infile closefile
                outfile closefile
                exit % exit the loop
        } ifelse
} bind loop
```

But when i try to read individual characters I get an error saying its typemismatch and i am unsure how to resolve it.

Here is the code:

```
/infile (input.txt) (r) file def % open files and save file objects
/outfile (output.txt) (w) file def
/buff 1 string def % your buffer for reading operations
{ % loop
        infile buff read
        { %ifelse
                outfile exch write
        }
        { %else
                outfile exch write
                infile closefile
                outfile closefile
                exit % exit the loop
        } ifelse
} bind loop
```

Answer (score 0):

So... Where does the error occur ? read, write ? something else ?

Whenever you debug PostScript this should be an important place to start, figure out which operator is throwing your error, and where in your program the error is thrown. If you aren't sure sprinkle 'print' and '==' around to follow the execution thread. Eg

```
    infile buff read
    { %ifelse
            (in read loop, character read is ) print dup == flush
            outfile exch write
    }
    { %else
            outfile exch write
            infile closefile
            outfile closefile
            exit % exit the loop
    } ifelse
```

Note that you are trying to write to outfile when 'read' returns false (your %else clause), that really isn't going to work, because 'read' didn't leave anything on the stack (it didn't read anything, that's why it returned false). I suspect this is your problem, though I haven't tried to debug the program other than desk checking.